# Why Cypress can't detect Chromium browser installed in my system?

Tags: cypress, chromium

```
$ uname -a
Linux [hostname] 3.10.0-1160.66.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 18 16:02:34 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm trying to run Cypress tests on a CentOS 7 server in Chromium, but it doesn't work.

Tests run fine in Electron on the same machine, and Cypress detects Firefox if I install it.

In my `cypress/plugins/index.js` I added some debugging code to demonstrate that Cypress can't even detect the Chromium browser:

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
    console.log(config.browsers)
    return {
        browsers: config.browsers.filter(
            b => b.name === 'chromium'
        )
    }
}
```

When I do `yarn cypress run --browser chromium`, the `console.log(config.browsers)` above  prints the following list of browsers along with some other messages:

```
$ yarn cypress run --browser chromium
yarn run v1.22.19
$ /path/repo/node_modules/.bin/cypress run --browser chromium
[148961:0704/093435.619286:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(377)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[148961:0704/093435.622068:ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported.
[
  {
    name: 'electron',
    channel: 'stable',
    family: 'chromium',
    displayName: 'Electron',
    version: '100.0.4896.75',
    path: '',
    majorVersion: 100,
    info: 'Electron is the default browser that comes with Cypress. This is the default browser that runs in headless mode. Selecting this browser is useful when debugging. The version number indicates the underlying Chromium version that Electron uses.'
  }
]
Your configFile as cypress.config.js set an invalid value:

Expected at least one browser
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

But I do have chromium installed:

```
$ which chromium-browser
/usr/bin/chromium-browser
$ yum info chromium | grep version -i
Version     : 114.0.5735.133
```

The whole point is to run Chromium with `--disable-gpu`, but Cypress doesn't even reach the `on('before:browser:launch')` stage where I can provide the argument.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install `brotli` simply because without it Chormium failed to start.

I found this out just by trying to run `chomium-browser` and getting the following error message:

```
$ chromium-browser
/usr/bin/chromium-browser: error while loading shared libraries: libbrotlidec.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I installed it:

```
yum install brotli
```